# ASP.NET Core 3.0: Display GIF when OnPost() gets hit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to put a GIF onto my website, and looking through other sources, I've found that I need to use a little bit of Ajax and Javascript to do so. However, I have no experience with either of them. Would anyone be able to post a solution for a web app using razor pages that would allow me to display a loading gif after I reach the onPost function on one of my pages? Any links would also be great! The solutions I've found so far seem to be for aspx files, and I don't have those within my project, nor do I understand how to convert the code to a cshtml / cshtml.cs format. Thank you for any help!

Edit: Going off the Demo that was posted in the solutions, I've been able to add in the script that was posted, but there are still issues.

This is the code that I have on my page:

```html
@page
@model CustomerPageTest.Pages.Assessment.UploadModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Upload";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-offset-2 justify-content-center">
    <h1 style="color:yellowgreen">3) Import RVTools Spreadsheet (.xls or .xlsx)</h1>
</div>
<br />
<br />

<div class="col-md-offset-3">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <tr style="border-top: hidden !important">
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.FormFile" type="file" class="text-light">
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.FormFile"></span>

                    <input asp-for="@Model.CustomerId" type="hidden" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.CustomerId"></span>

                    <input asp-for="@Model.AssessmentId" type="hidden" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.AssessmentId"></span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    <button id="buttonSubmit" asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn btn-dark" type="submit">Upload File</button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="position:center; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><img id="loadingImage" src="~/css/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading ..." style="display:none" /></div>
    </form>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#showGif').click(

            function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test",
                    method: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#loading').show();
                    }
                })

            }
        );

    </script>

}
```

As you can see I have a portion that takes in an Excel file, so my onPost cannot be a `JsonResult OnPost()` function, instead, it is a `Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(IFormFile files)`. I'm not sure how this affects the loading GIF. I also removed the token portion of the script because I don't completely understand what it is, but I don't think that it is needed here. Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, the solutions I've received for this haven't been enough to help me figure solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo worked:

test.cshtml:

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        </form>

        <img id="loading" src="~/Image/gif.gif" alt="Updating ..." style="display: none;" />
        <button id="showGif">show</button>
</div>
@section scripts{ 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#showGif').click(

            function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test",
                    method: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#loading').show();
                    }
                })
                
            }
        );
   
    </script>

}
```

test.cshtml.cs:

```
public JsonResult OnPost() {
            return new JsonResult("success");
        }
```

startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");

        }
```

result:
[image]

XSRF-token:

Razor Pages are designed to be automatically protected from cross-site request forgery (CSRF/XSRF) attacks. You don’t have to write any additional code. Antiforgery token generation and validation is automatically included in Razor Pages. In ajax post,the request fails, there is no AntiForgeryToken present on the page.So you need to add "XSRF-TOKEN" to the Header.

Use `<form method="post"></form>`so that you can find `$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()` in html

Since the script sends the token in a header called X-CSRF-TOKEN, configure the antiforgery service to look for the X-CSRF-TOKEN header:
 `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");`

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain the startup.cs portion a little just so I'm not implementing something that I don't completely understand?